# Interrupted time analysis ARIMA model

Tags: r, arima

I have the following annual data values for 2005 to 2017: (28.64,30.93,31.74,33.73,34.73,32.87,37.27,38.08,37.62,37.25,37.83,35.75,35.58). Year of intervention was 2013. May you assist in constructing a step by step R syntax to show the impact of the intervention, including graphs comparing counterfactual values against observed values post intervention.

Thank you all for helping.

I tried to develop a syntax but on my graph the step between the counterfactual values and observed values post intervention doesn't look ok. Also my step value is positive instead of negative.

Comment: What is your ARIMA model? You haven't shown us any code. Did you want to show just predictions along a linear regression of the first 9 values as your counterfactual?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what your ARIMA model was. Assuming you are doing something like `arima(values[1:8], order = c(1, 2, 3))`, then if you put your values in a data frame, then you could do something like:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Year = 2005:2017,
                 Value = c(28.64, 30.93, 31.74, 33.73, 34.73, 32.87, 37.27, 
                           38.08, 37.62, 37.25, 37.83, 35.75, 35.58))

df2 <- df
df2$Value <- c(df$Value[1:8],
      predict(arima(df$Value[1:8], order = c(1, 2, 3)), n.ahead = 5)$pred)

ggplot(df, aes(Year, Value, color = 'Actual')) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(color = 'Predictions based on\n2005 - 2012')) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(color = 'Predictions based on\n2005 - 2012')) +
  geom_line(lwd = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2013, linetype = 2) +
  annotate('text', x = 2012.75, y = 32, label = '2013 Intervention', angle = 90) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2005:2017) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c('black', 'red')) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to use autoarima to come up with the arima model? Secondly, I am also interested in getting the numerical values with 95% CI for the step and ramp. Thirdly, the values given are annual total DDD/TOPD (i.e. from January to December), so I am wondering if it is plausible to adjust intervention year to 2012 since intervention started at the beginning of 2013 (i.e. January) so that the vertical dotted line is between 2012 and 2013?